# the number is rounded in postgresql

Tags: python, sql, python-3.x, postgresql, heroku-postgres

I have a PostgreSQL in Heroku and Python code.

```
cursor.execute("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users (
    id bigserial PRIMARY KEY,
    item_id BIGINT,
    field_1 BIGINT,
    field_2 BIGINT,
    field_3 BIGINT,
    field_4 TEXT
)""")
```

Inputed data:

```
cursor.execute(f"INSERT INTO users (item_id, field_1, field_2, field_3, field_4) VALUES (821731693488584529, 0, 0, 0, 'None')")
```

I want, that `item_id` will be `821731693488584529`, but it is `821731693488584600`

How i can fix it?

Comment: Your code works fine in the database (https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=4b900b730a0810b80d2606a3b97d14e5).  The problem must be how you are displaying the number.

Comment: I send this request in Heroku and Python, but it's 821731693488584600

Comment: I can't replicate here using `psycopg2` and Postgres 13(not on Heroku). Are you sure you are  looking at correct database and/or table when retrieving the results?

Comment: Yes, it is True

Comment: Then choices 1) You have a trigger on the table that is doing something to the value 2) The way you are retrieving the data is changing the data. Add the code that does the retrieval to your question. 3) This is a Heroku bug and you will need to contact their support.

Comment: I suggest you to use `numeric` type

Comment: @Pooya, `821731693488584529` is perfectly valid `bigint` value. There is no reason to move to the overhead of `numeric` and no guarantee that whatever is causing the issue will not do the same with `numeric` values also.